# simple jQuery script not running

Tags: jquery

I just have copied a simple script from W3School and cannot get it running:
Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://Web Testing/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

It works on their Tryit Editor with the following line but does not work even with
this line on my Mac under BBEdit

Comment: Any errors? Look at your JavaScript Console

Comment: Your javascript source url seems to be wrong... `Web Testing` - a space in a url?

Answer (score 6):

you ned to include jquery the link you included is not working

try

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also useing the [google hosted](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) libraries is a good option  because many other website using it so in most case it will get in browser cache

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
   <!--left blank-->
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

       /*Your code*/

     });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://Web Testing/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

The link to the jquery library is invalid, replace that code with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Where should I put query-1.8.3.min.js file if I am using it for iOS app that works off-line?

Comment: put it at the top somewhere, it should be above all the other javascripts, feel free to accept this answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

you need to include jquery before use . or if you include jquery after script than  use ready or load event

tp include jquery you can either choose google hosted library or jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```